# error: cannot convert ‘float (*)(int)’ to ‘float’

Tags: c++

My program converts temperature from the Fahrenheit scale to the Celcius scale and finally to absolute value scale.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int farh;

float cels(int a)
{
    float c;
    const int m0 = 32;
    const float m1 = 0.5555;

    c=(a-m0)/m1;
    return c;
}

float ab(float a)
{
    const float m2 = 273.15;
    float d;

    d=a-m2;
    return d;
}

int main() {
    const int WIDTH = 16;

    cout << setiosflags ( ios :: left );
    cout << setw(WIDTH) << "Fahrenheit" << setw(WIDTH) << "Celcius" << setw(WIDTH) << "Absolute Value" << '\n';

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.precision(2);

    for (farh = 0 ; farh <= 300 ; farh = farh + 20) {
        cout.width(16);
        cout << farh << cels(farh) << ab(cels) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The Compile time error message I receive is:

```
d26.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
d26.cc:38:40: error: cannot convert ‘float (*)(int)’ to ‘float’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘float ab(float)’
   cout << farh << cels(farh) << ab(cels) << "\n";
```

Why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ab` takes a `float` and returns a `float`:

```
float ab(float a)
```

But `cels` isn't a `float`, it's a function:

```
float cels(int a)
```

You probably meant

```
ab(cels(farh))
```

Or to take a temporary:

```
float cur_cels = cels(farh);
cout << farh << cur_cels << ab(cur_cels) << "\n";
```

Side-note, `ab` should probably be named `kelvin`.

Comment: @BAarry
Works perfect with ab(cels(farh)).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have passed a funtion pointer to ab. if your intent is to pass the function ( clearly not! ) you can use the following syntax :

```
float ab(float(*callback)(int),int pass) {
  callback(pass); /* It calls the function indirectly with <pass> */
}
```

Its great for menu creation for example if you have two options:
1. Fahrenheit to Cell
2. Fahrenheit to Kelvin it will be useful

You can search **callback functions in C** with google.